# Issue when using multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have the following code. `generate(self, num)` is a class method that generates a set numbers and convert them into their binary representations:

```
def generate(self, num):
    M = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 64 - 1) for _ in range(num)]
    M = list(set(M))
    M = [('{0:0' + str(64) + 'b}').format(x) for x in M]
    M = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in M])
    return M

def run(self):
    M = []
    num = 10000
    mlp = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
    for i in xrange(0, num):
        res = mlp.apply_async(self.generate, args=(i,))
        M.append(res) # Here I think it is not good!!
    mlp.close()
    mlp.join()
```

The results appended into `M` is not correct and I get `<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x11ae6f690>`. How can I fix this code to achieve a parallelism is an efficient approach?

Comment: `res = mlp.apply_async(self.generate, args=(i,))` but `i` is incrementing, so what do you think happens with `M = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 64 - 1) for _ in range(num)]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `list` to share/exchange data between multiple processes, it's not thread safe. You should use `Manager` object for data manipulation between processes. A manager returned by Manager() will support types list, dict, Namespace, Lock, RLock, Semaphore, BoundedSemaphore, Condition, Event, Queue, Value and Array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code blows up having the `apply_async` inside a `for` loop so this might be the least of their worries

Answer (score 0):

Good notes from Medoo and Haifeng.  Take a look at the documentation on the multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object that you are getting back from the apply_async method.  You are just missing a method call on that object.

That object has the following method you can call, and I think that's all you are missing for your original question. Open that link at the bottom to see the other variations.

**get([timeout])**
*Return the result when it arrives. If timeout is not None and the result does not arrive within timeout seconds then multiprocessing.TimeoutError is raised. If the remote call raised an exception then that exception will be re raised by get().* This method will block until the results are returned or until the timeout is reached.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult